# What is 'Subscription' type in angular2?

Tags: angular

The following is some Angular 2 code:

```
private sub: Subscription;
ngOnInit(){
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let id = + params['id'];
        this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
    })
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me how `Subscription` works and what does it do in the above code?

Comment: This is a part of RxJs Observable. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscriptions are part of the RxJS extensions that are used in Angular 2. In this example you are subscribing to any change in the route parameters. When the route changes the callback function will be executed. You can read more about RxJS extensions https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS